# How do I set up AspectJ to log method calls in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, aspectj, aspects, jcabi

I'm making my first steps in Android development and to understand things like the lifecycle of a Fragment I'm using methods which have calls to a logger as the first line, such as

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    logger.debug("> onCreate(" + savedInstanceState + ")");
    ...
}
```

That works fine, except adding those messages to each method is rather cumbersome and it makes the code a bit hard to read. I found out that with [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) and other tools such as [jcabi-aspects](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-loggable.html) one could use something like this instead:

```
@Loggable(Loggable.DEBUG)
public String load(URL url) {
    return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

which would print:

```
[DEBUG] #load('http://www.google.com'): returned "<html ..." in 23ms
```

That sounds pretty cool, but how do I go about adding this functionality to Android Studio? I could find [a guide for Eclipse](http://blog.punegtug.org/2010/11/adding-aspect-to-android.html) and this [IntelliJ help page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-aspectj-support-plugins.html) (but not the mentioned plugins), and I'm at loss. I'd welcome a mini-guide on how to get started with AspectJ (and perhaps jcabi-aspects).

Answer (score 1):

The plug-ins mentioned on the IntelliJ help page can be found easily on my IDEA 13 installation:
[image: AspectJ plug-ins in IntelliJ IDEA]

As for Eclipse, the AspectJ support is much more mature than for IDEA because AspectJ itself is an Eclipse project. As much as I prefer IDEA for 95% of all my development use cases, when it comes to AspectJ support I use Eclipse. There you need to install the [AspectJ Development Tools (AJDT)](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/).

The best idea is to set up a Maven project for your Java + AspectJ endeavour, so you can build via command line or easily import the Maven project into both IDEA and Eclipse. You want to use the [AspectJ Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) for that purpose.

Learning AspectJ itself is possible via resources on the official [AspectJ documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php). There you find "getting started", "programming guide", "quick reference", "idioms", "pitfalls", "examples" and other sections.

Good luck!

P.S.: You could just have used your favourite web search engine to find what I just told you.

Comment: These plugins, however, are missing from Android Studio. So I'm sort of stuck.

Comment: Use Eclipse then or buy IDEA Ultimate.

Comment: To the person who downvoted my answer: Why did you do that? Downvotes are reserved for sloppily written, meaningless answers showing no sign of research or effort to answer comprehensively.